# How to store recognized faces so that they can be used when the app is closed and on different devices

Tags: java, android, face-recognition, mobile-development

Not sure if this is the right spot for this but I haven't been able to find anything useful online so any advice would be appreciated. Basically I'm working on a android facial recognition app that use firebase ml to detect faces and tensorflow to recognize faces. That all works fine but when I register a user I don't know how to store it on a server so that the face can be checked while on other devices or save the face to the original device so it doesn't need to be re-registered when the app is closed.

Ive looked for a while online and surprisingly couldn't find anything related to this. I have an idea in my head about a possible solution of saving a bitmap of the picture and then storing it locally and remotely on a SQL database but ideally if people with experience or a better understanding of this area could point me in the right direction that would be great!

This is my first project in the ML world and I am working off of this repository I found on github repository - https://github.com/estebanuri/face_recognition .

Its late here so I will answer any and all questions in the morning!

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.